# Can't hide a div for mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html, hide

Building a bootstrap theme for wordpress.
Trying to hide "sptxt" text from a mobile screen

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12"><div id="gr"></div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-7"><div class="hidden-sm" id="sptxt"><?php
$post_id = 34;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div></div>
</div>
```

It still shows. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Isn't it going to make it visible for small? I need it to be seen only on md and lg

Comment: It will make it invisible for extra small devices. Do you have a demo so that we can try to resize our browser and test it? Worst case, you could use media queries to hide the div. E.g 

`@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #custom-hide{ display: none; }  
}`

You need to replace the min-width & max-width by what you consider your  typical mobile screen size.

Comment: explanation of visible/hidden classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Answer (score 1):

A small device is like a kindle.  An extra small device is a phone like what you probably want to hide it for.  If you use

```
.hidden-sm
```

it will only hide for small screens, but still display for extra small and large screens.  You are probably looking for the

```
.hidden-xs
```

class.

Comment: updated in Bootstrap 4 to:

.hidden-xs-up .hidden-xs-down .hidden-sm-up .hidden-sm-down .hidden-md-up .hidden-md-down .hidden-lg-up .hidden-lg-down

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Answer (score 0):

I just set it visible for md and lg (.visible-md .visible-lg), leaving sm out of the code. Working perfectly now